# Where to start with teaching an AI to play SNES games?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I have had an infatuation with a certain concept regarding machine learning that Sethbling proved with his Mar.io program: https://youtu.be/qv6UVOQ0F44

I have a decent amount of logical programming experience in a number of different languages and have read around a lot about machine learning and neural networking.

What I'm looking for is a good set of references that could teach me how to apply neural networks in code, rather than just as a mathematical teaching like most of what I have seen thus far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sentdex (https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex) has incredible tutorials on Youtube and walks through teaching a model to play GTA.

It may seem daunting at first, but the rewards of overcoming such a challenging task will be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the JavaScript library [Neataptic](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/) to check out how they [implemented neural networks in Agar.IO](https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/agario/) for example.

You might also want to check out the [NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf) paper for a basic understanding of neuro-evolution.